# JPA/Hibernate relation working in one direction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got many to many relation between my tables parents and children.

This is the part from the Parent class which maps this relation :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "parents_children", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
protected Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
```

Here is the part in my Child class :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "children")
protected Set<Parent> parents;
```

Now this works from the parent side when I try to add children, if I had one Child object defined as `child` and one Parent object defined as `parent` :

```
parent.getChildren().add(child);
```

This updates correctly in db and it saves the entry to `parents_children` table.

However when I try to do it from the other end, from children I want to setParent(s). If I had `Set<Parent> parents` defined and I had `updateParents()` method defined inside my `Children` class and I had one child loaded from db defined as `child` and I tried this :

```
public void updateParents() {
    Set<Parent> parents = //get this from somewhere

    child.setParents(parents);
    update();
}
```

This will not work and I'm trying to figure out why. It will work if I modify my method to :

```
public void updateParents() {
  Set<Parent> parents = //get this from somewhere

  for (Parent parent : parents) {
    parent.getChild().add(this);
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with relation definition? I haven't use Java in a while and I'm having trouble with remembering this one.

Can someone point out to me what am I doing wrong so I can add parents to children objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with your definition. 
The problem is that `children` is the owning side of the association and unless you add the child to that set the database will not be updated.

You could change `parents` to map the same table, i.e. remove the `mappedBy` and thus effectively use two uni-directional associations, but that might cause problems when parents and children are updated.

Consider this case:

- Object A has children B and C
- Object B has parent A
- Object C has no parent (A is not in the `parents` set)

You now update A and C. Should C still be a child of A or not? The information is contradictory.

To resolve this, only one side should be responsible for updating the relation, which in your case would be A (by its `children` set).

Answer (score 0):

In JPA your responsible for managing both sides of an association.  This means that you must explicitly set a field on the one side of the relationship and add an element to a collection on the many side.

For example, consider a `Student` entity with a field `List<Course>` and assume a bidirectional `OneToMany`/`ManyToOne` relationship exists between both entities, `Student` and `Course`.

When adding a `Course` for a `Student` you would manage the relationship such as:

```
Course course = //findFromSomewhere;
Student student = //findEntity;

course.setStudent(student);
student.getCourses().add(course);
```

When persisting from the inverse side of the relationship you would manage the entities in the same way.

```
   course.setStudent(student);
   student.getCourses().add(course);
```

Just because you insert/update a field on one entity does not mean that Hibernate/JPA will automatically update the other side of the relationship for you.  Persisting like this would not update the other side of the association:

```
   //This would fail to add the course to the students list of courses.
   course.setStudent(student);
   em.persist(course);
```